# Android thread that runs on startup for entire life of the application

Tags: android

I am making an RPG style game with a character and I want the character's current health to increase every so often until its full health.

I have searched numerous articles and posts and i cannot seem to find anything to do this. My thoughts are to create a Thread or Handler in a global var class which extends Application.

I am using

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate()
 {
    super.onCreate();
    thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            // do something here
            System.out.println("GlobalVars - Sleeping");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

where instead of just printing, I will make my function call. Is this a good way to accomplish this? Can I implement an onPause and onResume for this thread incase the application gets interrupted by a phone call or they hit the home button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (or want) another thread for this.  Instead calculate health from the time.

```
long health = 1; // about to die
long healthAsOf = System.currentTimeMillis(); // when was health last calculated
long maxHealth = 100; // can't be more healthy than 100
long millisPerHealth = 60*1000; // every minute become 1 more healthy

public synchronized long getHealth() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long delta = now-healthAsOf;
    if( delta < millisPerHealth ) return health;
    long healthGain = delta/millsPerHealth;
    healthAsOf += millsPerHealth * healthGain;
    health = Math.min( maxHealth, health+healthGain );
    return health;

}

public synchronized void adjustForPause( long pauseMillis ) {

    healthAsOf += pauseMillis;

}
```

PS: You probably want to grab the time only once at the beginning of each frame so that the frame doesn't have things going on at slightly different times.